# Stochastic calculus: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, mathematics, itos-lemma

it is just the computation of a second moment but however is creating debate !!... Can someone spot the error?

[image: here is the problem]

Comment: It is a regular integral the second step... It becomes such because you are squaring Brownian motion and not considering terms of order higher than dt

Answer (score 2):

For a martingale $\{M_t \mid t\geq 0\}$ and the stochastic integral 
\begin{align*}
I_t = \int_0^tZ_s dM_s,
\end{align*}
we have that
\begin{align*}
E((I_t)^2) = E\bigg( \int_0^tZ_s^2 d\langle M\rangle_s\bigg),
\end{align*}
where $\langle M\rangle$ is the quadratic variation. That is, the ito's isometry holds for a martingale integrator only.

However, in your question, $\{X_t \mid t\geq 0\}$ is not a martingale, then
\begin{align*}
E\big( Y_t^2)\big) \neq E\bigg(\int_0^t (1+s)^2 d\langle X\rangle_s \bigg).
\end{align*}
Instead, since
\begin{align*}
Y_t^2 &= \bigg(4\int_0^t(1+s)ds + 6\int_0^t(1+s)W_sdW_s \bigg)^2\\
&=16\bigg( \int_0^t(1+s)ds\bigg)^2 + 48 \int_0^t(1+s)ds\int_0^t(1+s)W_sdW_s + 36 \bigg( \int_0^t(1+s)W_sdW_s\bigg)^2,
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
E\big( Y_t^2)\big) &= 16\bigg( \int_0^t(1+s)ds\bigg)^2 + 36 E\bigg[\bigg( \int_0^t(1+s)W_sdW_s\bigg)^2\bigg]\\
&=16\bigg( \int_0^t(1+s)ds\bigg)^2 + 36 E\bigg[\bigg( \int_0^t(1+s)^2W_s^2ds\bigg)\bigg]\\
&= 16\bigg( \int_0^t(1+s)ds\bigg)^2 + 36\int_0^t(1+s)^2 s\, ds.
\end{align*}

Comment: I see I was not considering the squared integral because somehow I ended up with ds^2... However thanks, your answer seems satisfactory, and I should put more attention between each step!